# How to show the searchbar and shoppingcart icon correctly with navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, font-awesome

I am trying to get a navbar to show me the menus both for bigscreen and mobile.  Having some trouble.

In bigscreen I am getting as required

```
webname   search:submit   menus                     menus      cart
```

[image: bigscreen display is correct]

But in the responsive mobile version, I am getting the search bar trying to take the entire row, with submit overlapping to the next line.

[image: mobile]

What I want is when mobile is used, show:

```
website name                      hambuger  

   search bar                  cart icon
```

```css
.mobileNav {
        position: absolute;
        right: 20px;
        top: 0px;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .mobileNav {
            position: absolute;
            right: 80px !important;
            top: 0px;
            width: 195px;
            text-align: right;
        }
        .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
            text-align: right;
            border: 1px solid #efefef;
            margin-top: 2px;
        }
        .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a,
        .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
        .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:active,
        .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
            background:none;
        }
    }

    #cart {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #cart > a {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px transparent solid;
        border-radius: var(--border-radius);
        color: inherit;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    #cart .badge:after{
        content:attr(value);
        font-size:12px;
        color: #fff;
        background: red;
        border-radius:50%;
        padding: 3 5px;
        position:relative;
        left:-8px;
        top:-10px;
        opacity:0.9;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BuyBrandedDomain</a>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="/action_page.php" data-toggle="collapse" >
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><div id="cart"><i class="fa badge fa-lg" value=11>&#xf07a;</i></div></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I understand I have to put the cart icon code outside the collapsible to make it appear when viewed in smaller screen. I want the cart to come in that location in big screen though, and not next to the search